# Android Studio error on double with two non 0 decimals

Tags: android

I have a problem on double with two non 0 decimals.
For example, if my double is 15.00 it is ok, but if my double is 15.55 my app crashes.
This is happening on my real phone (Galaxy s8+ - API 26), on all virtual devices from the android studio it works fine with all kinds of doubles (15.00 and 15.55).
Can someone help with this?

My code:

```
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");    
Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
Menu_price50.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price_50"))));

if(Category_ID == 1) {
    Menu_price100.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price_100"))));
}

Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));
```

Crash log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
              Process: com.ayurmed.ayucom, PID: 23974
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "14,5"
                  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
                  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
                  at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:503)
                  at com.ayurmed.ayucom.activities.ActivityMenuList.parseJSONData(ActivityMenuList.java:393)
                  at com.ayurmed.ayucom.activities.ActivityMenuList$getDataTask.doInBackground(ActivityMenuList.java:338)
                  at com.ayurmed.ayucom.activities.ActivityMenuList$getDataTask.doInBackground(ActivityMenuList.java:324)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: `my app crashes` with an exception and a stacktrace, which will show you the crash reason. Check it. (also post here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Please share your crash logs.

Comment: I do not know how to get my crash log from my phone. On android studio simulation (Virtual device works fine).

Comment: Someone, any ideas?

Comment: i made tests and the problem is with parseDouble.

Comment: `do not know how to get my crash log from my phone` there are many ways. You just need to search for more than 10 seconds to find one.

Comment: i posted crash log above

Comment: the problem is that `,` decimal separator. Try replacing all comas in that string to dots before parsing number

Comment: but i do not have coma in any string

Comment: even in my database is with dot

Comment: **You think** that you don't have, but the stacktrace says that you do have.

Comment: Finally i solved. Thanx to Vladyslav Matviienko